# Meteor: Shared helper not accessible from view js

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In a Meteor app, I have a shared helper:

[client/views/shared/shared_helpers.js]

```
Template.registerHelper('currentReport', function() {

  if( Meteor.user() ) {
    return Reports.findOne({ "userId": Meteor.user()._id });
  }

});
```

And in a view js [client/views/reports/report_show.js]

```
Template.report_show.rendered=function() {
  console.log( currentReport );
}
```

How come the view js can't access the `currentReport` helper?

I get: `ReferenceError: currentReport is not defined`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in a template you can refer to that global helper simply with `{{currentReport}}` from javascript you need to refer to it using `UI._globalHelpers.currentReport()`